# How to move code and associated button from one worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three worksheets, Pre-visit, Item List, and Search.

Pre-visit is the form. Item list is a database of all product codes and descriptions. Search is the worksheet I found. The search sheet works.

I moved the Search button from Search to Pre-visit and now it won't work.

```
Sub SearchParts()
    Dim arrParts() As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet, actsht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Search")
    sht.range("A7", "B" & Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B").End(xlDown).Row).Clear
    arrParts = FindParts(CStr(Trim(Cells(2, 2))))
    sht.range("A7").Resize(UBound(arrParts, 2), UBound(arrParts)) = _
      WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrParts)
End Sub
```

Original code

```
Sub SearchParts()
    Dim arrParts() As Variant
    range("A7", "B" & Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B").End(xlDown).Row).Clear
    arrParts = FindParts(CStr(Trim(Cells(2, 2))))
    range("A7").Resize(UBound(arrParts, 2), UBound(arrParts)) = _
      WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrParts)
End Sub


Private Function FindParts(PartNumber As String) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As range
    Dim LastCell As range
    Dim rngParts As range
    Dim FirstAddr As String
    Dim arrPart() As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("Item list")
    Set rngParts = ws.range("B5:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    With rngParts
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Set FoundCell = rngParts.Find(What:=PartNumber, After:=LastCell, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    End If

    ReDim arrPart(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        arrPart(1, UBound(arrPart, 2)) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -1)
        arrPart(2, UBound(arrPart, 2)) = FoundCell.Value

        ReDim Preserve arrPart(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrPart, 2) + 1)

        Set FoundCell = rngParts.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    FindParts = arrPart
End Function
```

Comment: Don't think I follow. The code will work on the specified sheet or whichever is active if nothing is specified.

Comment: `Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B")` should be `sht.Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "B")`.

Comment: @SJR Basically I have three worksheets involved with this problem. Called Pre-visit, Item List, and Search.

Pre-visit is the form. Item list is a database of all our product codes and descriptions. Search is the worksheet I found. The search sheet works great.

I need to enter products on the Pre-visit sheet, then have a list appear, I can do this through data validation. 

I can't get the search button on to the Pre-visit page and make it still work. Nothing happens.

As soon as I place it back where it belongs, on the Search sheet it works

Comment: `SearchParts` specifies the sheet "Search". That said `arrParts = FindParts(CStr(Trim(Cells(2, 2))))` doesn't specify a sheet so you should add a reference there.

Comment: @SJR How would I go about adding a reference there?

Comment: Well, as you have in other places - `worksheets("pre-visit").cells(2,2)`.

Comment: @SJR thank you, it is working now :)